# Pass Bytes to NodeJS Addon

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

I want to create a stream with the wav file, and pass it to my NodeJS addon:

```
var readableStream = fs.createReadStream('random_file.wav');
readableStream.on('data', function(chunk) {
        var chunck_to_binary = chunk.toString('what??'); //binary??
        var obj1 = addon.store(chunck_to_binary);
        console.log('chunck');
        console.log(obj1.caract_count);
        //console.log(typeof data);
    });
```

Then, when all the file has been passed. I want to to devolve the bytes to Nodejs, just to be shure that all process is correct. And create a copy:

```
readableStream.on('end', function() {
    console.log("loaded");

    var data_copy = addon.return_bytes();

    fs.writeFile('copy.wav', data_copy, function (err) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        console.log('done!!');
    });

});
```

In addon I implement some like this:

```
void store_values(const FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args) {
Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
HandleScope scope(isolate);

if (args.Length() < 1) {
    isolate->ThrowException(Exception::TypeError(
        String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Wrong number of arguments")));
    return;
}

v8::String::Utf8Value param1(args[0]->ToString());
std::string aux= std::string(*param1); //JS---->C++

//file_in_memory is global
file_in_memory = file_in_memory + aux;
//(..) return byte size of file_in_memory

}
```

So far I have not succeed. What is possible wrong? I think the problem is how I am passing the information to addon. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

`chunk` is a `Buffer`, which is good because it's basically just a chunk of bytes. Just pass to your add-on as-is:

```
var obj1 = addon.store(chunk);
```

In your add-on, you can convert it to `std::string` like so:

```
std::string aux(node::Buffer::Data(args[0]), node::Buffer::Length(args[0]));
```

Comment: In the first script which type of codification I should use? Binary?

Comment: @jdscardoso don't use `toString()` at all, just pass the `chunk` variable.

Comment: v8::Buffer:Data (...) give this alert: Error: name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name. Probably in new v8 the declaration of 'Buffer' changed. No?

Comment: @jdscardoso `node::Buffer::Data`, not `v8::Buffer::Data`

Comment: Sorry. I forget to #include <node_buffer.h>, so this why I make the modification. thanks again